# Putting legend on the subplots with Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to make a faceted plot with Plotly. Below you can see my code

```
library(plotly)

fig1 <- plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
  y = c(20, 14, 23),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar",marker = list(color = '#ff7f0e')
)

fig2 <- plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
  y = c(50, 24, 3),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar",marker = list(color = '#d62728')
)

fig3 <- plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
  y = c(10, 24, 67),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar",marker = list(color = '#9370DB')
)

fig4 <- plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
  y = c(10, 24, 67),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar",marker = list(color = '#2ca02c')
)
```

This code produces four plots, and now the next step is to put them together.

```
fig<-subplot(
  style(fig1, showlegend = TRUE),
  style(fig2, showlegend = TRUE),
  style(fig3, showlegend = TRUE),
  style(fig4, showlegend = TRUE),
  nrows = 2, margin = 0.05
)
fig
```

Output from the code above is the next figure.

[image]

You can see that in the top right corner, all legends are together instead of having a legend with each figure.

So can anybody help me how to solve this and to have a legend among each figure, as in the picture below?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to keep the legend functionality where you can click on parts of the legend to turn subplots on and off? Or just basically have a label for each color in the top right corner of each plot?

Comment: No I don't need legend functionality for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `subplot` one option would be to arrange your plots as separate containers where I use a `div` and `crosstalk::bscols` for convenience:

```
library(plotly)
library(htmltools)

legend <- list(orientation = "v", y = 1, x = .85)

fig1 <- plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
  y = c(20, 14, 23),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar", marker = list(color = "#ff7f0e"),
  legendgroup = "1"
) |>
  layout(showlegend = TRUE, legend = legend)

fig2 <- plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
  y = c(50, 24, 3),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar", marker = list(color = "#d62728"),
  legendgroup = "2"
) |>
  layout(showlegend = TRUE, legend = legend)

fig3 <- plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
  y = c(10, 24, 67),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar", marker = list(color = "#9370DB")
) |>
  layout(showlegend = TRUE, legend = legend)

fig4 <- plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
  y = c(10, 24, 67),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar", marker = list(color = "#2ca02c")
) |>
  layout(showlegend = TRUE, legend = legend)

htmltools::div(
  crosstalk::bscols(
    fig1, fig2
  ),
  crosstalk::bscols(
    fig3, fig4
  )
) |>
  htmltools::browsable()
```

[image]